# Compensation because of cancelled flight: was there a baggage handler strike on July 2nd?

Tags: uk, eu, cancellations, compensation, industrial-action

I was booked on flight BA 363 from LYS (Lyon) to LHR (London) on July 2nd 2022. The flight was cancelled - reasons not specified at the time - and I have applied for compensation plus costs. Unknown to BA, I was part of a group of 25 that all booked for this flight independently as individuals, so we have been able to compare notes on BA's response to compensation claims. In many cases, but not all, they are refusing compensation on the grounds that the cancellation was due to a baggage handlers' strike.

Is there any way of verifying whether there was actually a baggage handlers' strike on that day? All the press coverage states that flight cancellations were due to staff shortages, which is a different matter entirely, as staff shortages are considered to be entirely under the control of the airline and its subcontractors.

Comment: At which airport would have the strike happened? At LYS or at LHR?

Comment: If they want to involve force majeure, it’s up to them to prove it, which first involved being precise about who was striking and where…

Answer (score 4):

Local/Regional media usually covers well such strikes

According to regional media [France 3 Auvergne Rhone-Alpes](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/auvergne-rhone-alpes/rhone/lyon/aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-30-vols-annules-ce-samedi-2-juillet-2574868.html) (fr),

> > Un mouvement de grève des personnels au sol se poursuit à l'aéroport de Lyon Saint Exupéry ce samedi 2 juillet 2022. Les passagers de 30
> > avions n'ont pas pu décoller comme prévu.
>
> C'est la sixième journée de grève des personnels au sol de
> l'entreprise Aviapartner à l'aéroport de Lyon Saint Exupéry.  Agents
> de guichets, bagagistes, contrôleurs, chargés d'enregistrement
> [...]

> > A strike of ground staff is continuing at Lyon Saint Exupéry this Saturday July, 2nd 2022. Passengers from 30 flights didn't takeoff as
> > expected
>
> This is the 6th day of strike of ground personnel from company
> Aviapartner at Lyon Saint Exupéry, ticket office personnel, baggage
> handlers, guards, check-in agents [...]

(Emphasis and translation mine)

there was indeed a ground staff strike at Lyon `LYS` on July, 2nd 2022. And this included baggage handlers

There doesn't seem to have a strike at LHR, but the chaos there might not have helped.

Comment: Thank you. Some of the letters from BA (not all) blamed strike action at Heathrow.